# Segfault reading from shared memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fork, shared-memory

I am working on a homework problem to write an implementation of the collatz conjecture in C using fork() and a shared memory object, performing the calculations in the child process and printing out the results in the parent. I'm not terribly familiar with C, so im learning a lot of the tools. Using gdb, I identified a segfault when I try to access the object in the parent process. I am using Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

const int SIZE  = 4096;
const char *name = "SM";
int shm_fd;
void  *ptr;

pid_t child;


if ((argc != 2) || (strtol(argv[1],NULL, 10) <= 0))
{
        printf("Invalid usage: requires 1 positive integer parameter\n");
        return -1;
}

child = fork();
if(child >=0 )
{
        if (child == 0)
        {
                shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT || O_RDWR, 0666);
                ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
                ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
                int currentval = strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
                sprintf(ptr,"%d",currentval);
                ptr++;/*  floor(log10(abs(currentval))) + 1;*/
                while (currentval > 1)
                {
                        sprintf(ptr, ", ");
                        ptr += 2;
                        if (currentval % 2 == 1)
                        {
                                currentval = currentval * 3 + 1;
                                sprintf(ptr, "%d", currentval);
                                ptr++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                currentval = currentval/2;
                                sprintf(ptr, "%d", currentval);
                                ptr++;
                        }
                }
                sprintf(ptr, "\n");
                ptr+= 1;
                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
                wait();

                shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666);
                ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
                printf("%s\n",(char *)ptr);
                shm_unlink(name);
                return 0;
        }
}
else
{
        printf("error creating child process\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

I've never debugged a segfault before so any advice would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It was doing a logical OR instead of a bitwise OR, so was creating a bad file descriptor.

shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT || O_RDWR, 0666);

should have been

shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

Answer (score 1):

I know this is unrelated to what you asked but since I came across this question, for the others who may also come across might find the following useful:

While reading and printing the series for Collatz conjecture, if the example taken is 8, the program above runs fine, as the answer to it is: 8, 4, 2, 1
But if you try running it for 10, the answer for it is: 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 whereas the above program will only show: 1, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1. Because it will read a single char at a time. And so there is a little modification required here.

```
int shift = 0;
char store[sizeof(int)];
while (currentval > 1)
{
        sprintf(ptr, ", ");
        ptr += 2;
        if (currentval % 2 == 1)
        {
                currentval = currentval * 3 + 1;
        }
        else
        {
                currentval = currentval/2;
        }
        sprintf(store, "%s", currentval);  /* Convert the number to a string */
        sprintf(ptr, "%s", store); /* Store the string */ 
        shift = strlen(store);
        ptr += shift;
}
sprintf(ptr, "\n");
ptr+= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the backtrace of the core file which is created using gdb:

```
gdb -c <core file> <executable>
```

it will open the core in gdb, then type "bt" . This will get you the exact location where the problem was. You can also paste that output here.

Comment: I think the reason might be that your mmap might be failing. You are using the pointer without even checking for error conditions. mmap on failure returns "-1" and sets the error number.

Comment: I get two core files when I do a dump. The child is:
`0  0x00832f25 in _IO_str_overflow_internal () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x00831abf in _IO_default_xsputn_internal () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#2  0x0080c4e8 in vfprintf () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#3  0x00827b1b in vsprintf () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#4  0x00814e3b in sprintf () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#5  0x0804865d in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfea2e84) at problem_3_21.c:42`

Comment: The bt from the parent : `#0  0x0083c26b in strlen () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x0080f821 in vfprintf () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#2  0x00814dc0 in printf () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#3  0x08048748 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfea2e84) at problem_3_21.c:68
`

Comment: Clearly "ptr" you are getting from mmap is wrong. Handling error cases of mmap will help you resolve the problem of segmentation. Also check why mmap is not working.